# Odd geometry deformations with cloth objects

Tags: cloth-simulation, rigid-body-simulation

I recently  attempted to make an animation which shows a series of cubes hitting and bouncing off a pinned sheet, where the cubes can also interact and bounce off each other. For the pinned sheet both collision & cloth settings are enabled. The cubes all have collision, cloth, rigid body and rigid body constraint settings enabled (I just fiddled around until they interacted with both the sheet and each other).

Anyway it all starts off very well, until about 00:07 when one of the cubes totally flips out and deforms in a very strange way... The other cubes then get a bit confused, stop falling and just hang in mid-air, whilst the cloth has a freak out and wraps itself around the stationary cubes. Can anyone think of a reason why this happens? Is it my settings, or is it a bug in Blender? Has anyone else had the same problem?

I've uploaded the animation to my blog here:
http://variabledimensions.tumblr.com/post/80251427750/cubefa-i-ll-more-experiments-with-blender-cubes

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please upload your blend file so we can take a look at it?